Script for enabling HDR on a single monitor
I have two monitors that have HDR capability but one of them is pretty bad so I prefer to enable it for only one of them. However, when I go to Display Settings and enable HDR, both get turned on. Then I need to toggle it off, which turns it off for both monitors, then toggle it on again, which finally toggles it on for only the monitor I selected.
Is there a way I can make a script that specifically only turns on HDR for one monitor?
